# Формат "дд.мм.гг."

Tags: орфография

Можно ли добавлять слово "года" к дате в формате "дд.мм.гг."? Или он не допускает никаких добавлений?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю - нет. Тавтология получается. Год уже и так есть в дате.